# Can't connect to snowflake via unixODBC. Error: [S1000][unixODBC][Snowflake][ODBC] (11560) Unable to locate SQLGetPrivateProfileString function

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unixodbc

I've installed/configured the drivers per the instructions here:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/odbc-linux.html#installing-and-configuring-the-odbc-driver-for-linux

Getting the error: [S1000][unixODBC][Snowflake][ODBC] (11560) Unable to locate SQLGetPrivateProfileString function.

I found a post that says to install and use another driver (libodbcinst.so.2), but that didn't work either.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04

Here's the debug:

```
$ isql -v snowflake_dev my_username my_password
2020-01-02T20:48:43.123 INFO  4442 Snowflake::Client::IFileTransferAgent.cpp::: External logger injected. libsnowflakeclient version: 0.4.2
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 SharedSingletonManager::LogVersions: SDK Version: 10.01.15.1109
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 SharedSingletonManager::LogVersions: DSII Version: 2.20.2
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 Driver::Initialize: Database CHAR Encoding: UTF-8
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 Driver::Initialize: Database WCHAR Encoding: UTF-32LE
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 Driver::Initialize: Driver ANSI CHAR Encoding: UTF-8
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 Driver::Initialize: Driver Manager WCHAR Encoding: UTF-16LE
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 Driver::Initialize: Detected Driver Manager: unixODBC, 2.2.14 or 2.3.x branch
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 Driver::Initialize: Locale name: en_US
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 Driver::Initialize: Bitness: 64-bit
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 CInterface::SQLAllocHandle: Allocating environment handle.
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 Environment::SQLSetEnvAttr: Attribute: SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION (200)
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 EnvironmentAttributes::SetAttribute: Setting ODBC version to: 2
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 Environment::SQLGetEnvAttr: Attribute: SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION (200)
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 CInterface::SQLAllocHandle: Allocating connection handle.
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 ConnectionSettings::ConnectionSettings: DSN = "snowflake_dev"
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 ConnectionSettings::ConnectionSettings: UID = "*****"
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 ConnectionSettings::ConnectionSettings: PWD specified.
Jan 02 20:48:43 DEBUG 2785285952 BinaryFile::BinaryFile: opening file "/var/snowflake_odbc/ErrorMessages/en-US/ODBCMessages.xml" with openmode=OPENMODE_READONLY
Jan 02 20:48:43 ERROR 2785285952 Connection::SQLConnectW: [Snowflake][ODBC] (11560) Unable to locate SQLGetPrivateProfileString function.
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 CInterface::SQLFreeHandle: Freeing connection handle.
Jan 02 20:48:43 INFO  2785285952 CInterface::SQLFreeHandle: Freeing environment handle.
[S1000][unixODBC][Snowflake][ODBC] (11560) Unable to locate SQLGetPrivateProfileString function.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Comment: Is your driver manager directory  included in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable? https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/odbc-linux.html#simba-snowflake-ini-file-driver-manager-and-logging

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the ODBCInstLib in my simba.snowflake.ini file
Default was wrong and needed to be changed to:
ODBCInstLib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so

Answer (score 6):

The problem was the ODBCInstLib config in my simba.snowflake.ini file was wrong and needed to be changed to: ODBCInstLib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so

Comment: Didn't have this problem on redhat but when building our docker which uses debian I had the same issue